# postMessage and event listener only works sometimes

Tags: javascript, events, dynamics-crm, postmessage

I have a web resource embedded on my CRMform.  Its easy to submit the data to CRM but a bit more tricky to populate the web resource (html page) with data from CRM onLoad.

With that being said I have a js file with postMessage as so:

```
iFrame.contentWindow.postMessage(postObj, 'https://server.xrm.com/crmOrg/WebResources/htmlPageToPostMessageTo');
```

The following js on another HTML page holds the listener for the postMessage as follows:

```
            $(window).on('message',
               function(event) {

                    // Important. Only accept messages from trusted origins.
                    if (~event.originalEvent.origin.indexOf('https://server.xrm.com')) {
                        var messageData = event.originalEvent.data;
                        //#1
                        if (messageData.attribute)
                        {
                           ....do stuff......
                         }
```

This behaves very strangely as in sometimes it hits the listener and sometimes it doesn't

In the debugger, it does seem that the following is async:

```
                    if `(~event.originalEvent.origin.indexOf('https://server.xrm.com')) {...`
```

Im fairly certain that there is a timing issue.

Can anybody provide any suggestions?

This is having me and my other dev pull our hair out.

Regards.

Comment: Maybe try adding a `console.log()` at the start of the listener (before the origin check) to see if it's being called every time?

Comment: We actually just fixed it lol....added a quick timeout before postMessage and works like a charm.

Comment: A fixed delay can prove to be a brittle solution. Apparently the page of the web resource needs some time to load. Why not wait for the status to be changed to ready?

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen  I agree, a fixed timeout is definitely not an optimal solution.  We did have it as onReadyState but still wasn't working for some reason.  We are looking into it.  The quick fix did help in the fact that we needed to push to production that night.

Answer (score 1):

It took me sometime to find a workaround, but this seems to fix the issue as you guys have suggested

```
Promise.resolve(setTimeout(
  () => {
    iFrame.contentWindow?.postMessage(postObj, 'https://...')
  }, 200),
)
```